# CJK fonts with bib2gls

Tags: cjk, miktex2.9, bib2gls

I'm having difficulty displaying CJK fonts in a glossary with bib2gls. I'm using MikTeX, which I think may produce different results to TeXLive. Here's a MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{CJKutf8}
\usepackage[record,style=indexgroup,nomain]{glossaries-extra}

\newglossary*{japanese}{Japanese to English}
\newglossary*{english}{English to Japanese}

\newrobustcmd{\cjkname}[1]{\begin{CJK}{UTF8}{ipxm}#1\end{CJK}}
\glsnoexpandfields

\newcommand*{\englishlettergroup}[1]{#1}
\newcommand*{\japaneselettergroup}[1]{\cjkname{#1}}
\newcommand*{\bibglslettergrouptitle}[4]{\unexpanded{\csuse{#4lettergroup}{#1}}}

\GlsXtrLoadResources[
  src=testcjk2,% bib file
  sort={ja-JP},% locale used to sort primary entries
  dual-sort={en-GB},% locale used to sort secondary entries
  type=japanese,% put the primary entries in the 'japanese' glossary
  dual-type=english% put the dual entries in the 'english' glossary
]

\begin{document}

\begin{CJK}{UTF8}{ipxm}日本語はだいじょうぶ\end{CJK}

Japanese: \gls{squareroot}

English: \gls{dual.squareroot}

\printunsrtglossaries
\end{document}
```

Where the file testcjk2.bib is

```
@dualentry{squareroot,
  name={\cjkname{ルート}},
  description={square root}
}
```

The MWE comes from an answer [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/390201/glossaries-with-cjk-characters). The resulting document looks as shown below. The Japanese text from `\begin{CJK}{UTF8}{ipxm}日本語はだいじょうぶ\end{CJK}` displays fine, but that from the .bib file does not. Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: @gusbrs It's a good guess, I also had the same idea, but it appears not to change anything.

Comment: James, yes, I tried it here without it, and I can't reproduce the issue (it works as expected here). Sorry I deleted the original comment, leaving yours hanging, but it was a bad guess. Anyway, I'm using TeXLive, so if you are assuming there might be a difference with MikTeX, it may well be. So I can't really be of much help.

Comment: Indeed, `CJKuft8` does already load `[uft8]{inputenc}`.

Comment: Try adding `% Encoding: UTF-8` at the start of the `.bib` file.

Comment: I updated MikTek and everything seems to work fine now. It appears that the version of MikTek I had was missing something necessary.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the issue was solved by an update of MikTeX.

Comment: unfortunately I am facing similar errors with TexLive and apparently there's no way to fix it, which is quite a bummer, as the example from the original question would be a perfect solution for me if it just worked :(