# verbatim and CJK

Tags: fonts, verbatim, cjk, typewriter

I'm not familiar with chinese characters and fonts. But I have to type some characters into a document. `XeLaTeX` may be an option, but I'm looking for a solution with `pdflatex`. Here is my MWE, which I created with the help of other questions and answers:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{CJKutf8}
\begin{document}
\begin{CJK*}{UTF8}{gbsn}
中華人民共和國

ABC-1234
\begin{verbatim}
中華人民共和國
ABC-1234
\end{verbatim}
\end{CJK*}
\end{document}
```

I have two questions:

1. Is there a monospace font for chinese characters available for using in `verbatim` environments with same size than latin characters (I'm using MacTeX/TeXLive 2012)?
2. Why are not all 7 chinese symbols in the resulted pdf?

[image: result of pdflatex]

Comment: with the help of http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/94293/how-to-input-kana-with-pdflatex I changed `gbsn` to `maru` or `bkai`. With these fonts, all 7 chinese symbold are in the generated pdf. So, I'm only looking for a fixed font, too.

Comment: Fixed font means monospaced font, right. As far as I know all Chinese fonts are monospaced... Of course, the character width of `中` is different from an `A`. So you want `A` and `中` to have the same width?

Comment: yes, I've edited my posts

Comment: If you change to the `bsmi` family (instead of `gbsn`), you'll get all the characters.

Comment: For CJK scripts, monospaced usually means that a *fullwidth* character (e.g. `中`) is **twice** as wide as a *halfwidth* character (e.g. `A`). In fact it is more difficult to obtain this monospaced feature.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[image: output of MWE]

1. The ASCII characters `ABC...` are usually typeset as *halfwidth* characters while Chinese characters (`汉字，　ＡＢＣ．．．`) are typeset as *fullwidth* characters. See also [Halfwidth and fullwidth forms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halfwidth_and_fullwidth_forms).

   Hence, a solution is to convert the ASCII characters to fullwidth ones in Unicode. You might write your own converter or use a website like http://kiserai.net/hwfw.pl
2. There are two writing systems for Chinese characters: the traditional and the simplified system. The characters `華` and `國` belong to the traditional characters, while the others can be used in both systems. Unfortunately, there is no one-to-one mapping between traditional characters and simplified ones. Several traditional characters can be mapped to one simplified one.

   Hence, when using a `CJK` environment you also need to decide which writing system, i.e., which font to use: `gbsn` and `gkai` are fonts with simplified characters, while `bsmi` and `bkai` are fonts with traditional characters. See also [Problems of traditional and simplified Chinese characters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debate_on_traditional_and_simplified_Chinese_characters#Problems)
   and [`CJK` environment and Chinese](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Internationalization#Chinese)

Here is the code of the above picture:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{CJKutf8}
\begin{document}
\begin{CJK}{UTF8}{bsmi}
中華人民共和國

ABC-1234
\begin{verbatim}
中華人民共和國
ＡＢＣ－１２３
４
\end{verbatim}
\end{CJK}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Yes I wondered about mentioning the possibility of changing the input, This is probably the "right" thing to do.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle It is probably also possible to map `A` (U+0041) to `Ａ` (U+FF21), `B` to `Ｂ`, and so on just within the "verbatim" environment. Hence, no external conversion is needed. (But not sure how to do that...)

Answer (score 3):

This makes all the ascii characters twice their normal width, I thought that would make them exactly line up but it seems to be drifting slightly, an alternative would be 2o replace `2\noexpand\width` by a fixed with pre-calculated to be the width of the CJK characters in the verbatim font. It doesn't work as written if there are accented characters or other half width characters out of the ASCII range.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{CJKutf8}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\makeatletter
\def\verbatim@processline{%
\edef\tmp{\expandafter\cjkpad\the\verbatim@line\relax}
\tmp}

\def\cjkpad#1{%
\ifx\relax#1\par
\else
\ifnum\expandafter`\noexpand#1<128 %
\noexpand\makebox[2\noexpand\width]{\noexpand#1}%
\else
\noexpand#1%
\fi
\expandafter\cjkpad
\fi}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{CJK*}{UTF8}{bsmi}

\makeatletter

中華人民共和國

ABC-1234


\begin{verbatim}
中華人民共和國
ABC-1234
\end{verbatim}
\end{CJK*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: it works fine, but with a value 1.9 instead of 2 it looks better for me.

Answer (score 1):

```
% UTF-8 encoding
% Compile with XeLaTeX
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xeCJK}

% Specify a Chinese font that contains all characters you need.
\setCJKmainfont{SimSun}

\begin{document}
中華人民共和國

ABC-1234

A fullwidth character is twice as wide as a halfwidth character:
\begin{verbatim}
|中華人民共和國|
|ABC-1234......|
\end{verbatim}
\end{document}
```

[image]